# CDC COVID Vaccine Administration Time Series Data?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, covid-19-datasets

For context, in the past the CDC has published time series data of COVID case counts by State: https://healthdata.gov/dataset/united-states-covid-19-cases-and-deaths-state-over-time

Now, CDC are beginning to publish vaccination distribution/administration information by State. However, best as I can tell, vaccine administration counts by State are only kept on a live web page and has not yet been turned into time series: https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/#vaccinations

Is my best recourse for now to suggest pulling daily counts by State with the Wayback machine? Curious if anyone has found this data hosted elsewhere? I looked on Healthdata.gov, where the case counts time series is hosted, and only found counts on vaccine shipments by State - not counts of the vaccines administered, which that live-updated page hosts (https://healthdata.gov/search/type/dataset?query=vaccine&sort_by=changed&sort_order=DESC).

I'm not interested in live web pages hosted by NYT/Bloomberg - would prefer to get direct from the source. Bloomberg reported (https://www.bloomberg.com/graphics/covid-vaccine-tracker-global-distribution/) they edit the vaccine data they publish a bit: 'Local governments and the CDC sometimes report different totals for the same jurisdiction; in these cases Bloomberg uses the higher number.'